# Creating a List and parsing through it in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, list

So I have a column1 with entries in form of an XML string. My task is to parse through this XML string and sub divide the output to print sub nodes in the string.
For example,
The dataset looks something like this:

```
<ParameterValues>
        <ParameterValue>
             <Name>A</Name>
             <Value>1</Value>
        </ParameterValue>
        <ParameterValue>
             <Name>B</Name>
             <Value>1</Value>
        </ParameterValue>
        <ParameterValue>
             <Name>C</Name>
             <Value>3</Value>
        </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

I need to print Name column of all the names and Value column of all the values.
Something like this:

- Name     -  Value
- A      -     1
- B         -  2
- C        -   3

I have two obstacles I am stuck at. 
First, How may I store this "table" of x "columns" in a list to parse through the list one dataset at a time.
Second, I can start working on it once I have solved this problem.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2005 & higher version, using xml datatype, & Xquery you can do this.. I've written some t-sql here try it. [ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0097/15 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Xml XML = N'<ParameterValues>
                         <ParameterValue>
                             <Name>A</Name>
                             <Value>1</Value>
                          </ParameterValue>
                          <ParameterValue>
                              <Name>B</Name>
                              <Value>1</Value>
                          </ParameterValue>
                          <ParameterValue>
                              <Name>C</Name>
                              <Value>3</Value>
                          </ParameterValue>
                    </ParameterValues>'
```

### Query

```
SELECT x.a.value('Name[1]','varchar(10)') AS Name
       ,x.a.value('Value[1]','varchar(10)') AS Value
FROM @Xml.nodes('/ParameterValues/ParameterValue') x(a)
```

### Result Set

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ Name ║ Value ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ A    ║     1 ║
║ B    ║     1 ║
║ C    ║     3 ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, certainly made it seem easy :) I nvr knew SQL has a XML type to

Comment: but with all due respect I originally asked how many I create a list of strings in SQL. This particular string comes from a query; "Select table from database" I am looking for somehow store this table output into a list of strings and each string can further be solved using the solution you provided as well.